# OSGI Pax logging

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-fragment, pax-runner, jbossfuse

I want to write a custom appender which will collect all the logs coming to Fuse.log in Fuse container and relay them over Scribe to a central log store. I want to add a event listener for that in the container. But I couldn't figure out how I can do that. I went through the PAX logging code. But couldn't figure out. 
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote once a blog post about this, it can be found at [my blog](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2011/08/adding-custom-log-appender-to-pax-logging/).
Basically you just need to create your appender, the tricky part is in adding it to pax-logging in the container via a fragment bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your blog and everything worked fine.

Comment: Hey @AchimNierbeck can you help on this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232220/add-custom-log4j2-appender-for-karaf-and-pax-logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232220/add-custom-log4j2-appender-for-karaf-and-pax-logging)

Answer (score 1):

pax logging just uses log4j as the implementation. So I would write a log4j appender to do this instead. here is a library which does this already, but I've never touched it. https://code.google.com/p/scribe-log4j/