# Add custom log4j2 appender for Karaf and Pax Logging

Tags: log4j2, apache-karaf

I am trying to add new custom log4j2 appender. Karaf 3.0.2 use pax-logging 1.7.4 which does not support log4j2. I have a appender which extend **org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender**.

I followed this blog http://blog.nanthrax.net/2012/12/create-custom-log4j-appender-for-karaf-and-pax-logging/ writen by Jean-Baptiste. It will not work because my appender is written in log4j2.

What are the alternatives so that karaf also log using this appender?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is already in your question it doesn't work, and how is it supposed to. 
Version 3.0.2 of Karaf does use Pax Logging 1.7.x wich doesn't support Log4j2.
So you just can't register a custom appender for log4j2, create a Log4j appender and add that to your configuration.
Or upgrade to Karaf 3.0.3 which uses Pax Logging 1.8.x which now also support Log4j2. Might want to try that.

Comment: Thank You Achim, I downloaded karaf 3.0.3, first i tried to print a log using log4j2 `LogManager.getLogger()`. I am getting error `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console`. What does it mean?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-373 This should notbe the problem as i am using 2.1 version of log4j in my pom.xml. Any pointers?

Comment: Also getting error `Unable to resolve 112.0: missing requirement [112.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.logging.log4j)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))`.    I think we dont need to install log4j-api and log4-core  bundles manually as karaf should provide these bundles.

Comment: Better ask such questions at the karaf mailinglist.

Comment: I written a post in old thread http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Were-you-guys-still-interested-in-adopting-Log4j2-for-your-logging-system-td4033296.html.

Comment: can you help me regarding log4j2 with karaf? open that mailing link i had a conversation with JB.